# c++11 shared_ptr using in multi-threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Recently I'm thinking a high performance event-driven multi-threads framework using c++11. And it mainly takes c++11 facilities such as `std::thread`, `std::condition_variable`, `std::mutex`, `std::shared_ptr` etc into consideration. In general, this framework has three basic components: job, worker and streamline, well, it seems to be a real factory. When user construct his business model in server end, he just needs to consider the data and its processor. Once the model is established, user only needs to construct data class inherited job and processor class inherited worker.

For example:

```
class Data : public job {};
class Processsor : public worker {};
```

When server get data, it just new a Data object through `auto data = std::make_shared<Data>()` in the data source callback thread and call the streamline. `job_dispatch` to transfer the processor and data to other thread. Of course user doesn't have to think to free memory. The streamline. `job_dispatch` mainly do below stuff:

```
void evd_thread_pool::job_dispatch(std::shared_ptr<evd_thread_job> job) {
    auto task = std::make_shared<evd_task_wrap>(job);
    task->worker = streamline.worker;  
    // worker has been registered in streamline first of all
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(streamline.mutex);
        streamline.task_list.push_back(std::move(task));
    }
    streamline.cv.notify_all();
}
```

The `evd_task_wrap` used in the `job_dispatch` defined as:

```
struct evd_task_wrap {
    std::shared_ptr<evd_thread_job> order;
    std::shared_ptr<evd_thread_processor> worker;
    evd_task_wrap(std::shared_ptr<evd_thread_job>& o)
    :order(o) {}
};
```

Finally the task_wrap will be dispatched into the processing thread through `task_list` that is a `std::list` object. And the processing thread mainly do the stuff as:

```
void evd_factory_impl::thread_proc() {
    std::shared_ptr<evd_task_wrap> wrap = nullptr;
    while (true) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(streamline.mutex);
            if (streamline.task_list.empty())
                streamline.cv.wait(lck, 
                [&]()->bool{return !streamline.task_list.empty();});
            wrap = std::move(streamline.task_list.front());
            streamline.task_list.pop_front();
        }
        if (-1 == wrap->order->get_type())
            break;
        wrap->worker->process_task(wrap->order);
        wrap.reset();
    }
}
```

But I don't know why the process will often crash in the `thread_proc` function. And the coredump prompt that sometimes the wrap is a empty shared_ptr or segment fault happened in `_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace::_M_dispose` that is called in wrap.reset(). And I supposed the shared_ptr has the thread synchronous problem in this scenario while I know the control block in shared_ptr is thread-safety. And of course the shared_ptr in `job_dispatch` and `thread_proc` is different shared_ptr object even though they point to the same storage. Does anyone has more specific suggestion on how to solve this problem? Or if there exists similar lightweight framework with automatic memory management using c++11

---

The example of process_task such as:
`void log_handle::process_task(std::shared_ptr<crx::evd_thread_job> job) {
    auto j = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<log_job>(job);
    j->log->Printf(0, j->print_str.c_str());
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, j->print_str.c_str(), j->print_str.size());
}
class log_factory {
public:
    log_factory(const std::string& name);
    virtual ~log_factory();
    void print_ts(const char *format, ...) {  //here dispatch the job
        char log_buf[4096] = {0};
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, format);
        vsprintf(log_buf, format, args);
        va_end(args);
        auto job = std::make_shared<log_job>(log_buf, &m_log);
        m_log_th.job_dispatch(job);
    }
public:
    E15_Log m_log;
    std::shared_ptr<log_handle> m_log_handle;
    crx::evd_thread_pool m_log_th;
};`

Comment: >Recently I'm thinking a high performance event-driven multi-threads framework using c++11. It's ok for just learning purposes otherwise I will discourage you in pursuing this, use ASIO.

Comment: @Arunmu It's so huge that I only want a lightweight framewrok.When I want to satisfy some specific demands, I can fix the source to meet them quickly.But the Asio can't response so quickly.

Comment: That is not a good way to think. You will end up giving more time debugging, fixing your own framework than using ASIO which I guess would take atmax 1 day to integrate and working with good performance.

Comment: I don't see any issue in the given code. It's probably elsewhere. You wouldn't actually need shared_ptr here, since you never access the objects from both threads. It's either on the writer side, then you donate it to the queue, and then you fetch it from there. So a unique_ptr is also fine.

Comment: You might not be aware that [Asio](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.10.6/doc/asio/using.html) can be used as a standalone library. But I agree with others, that it's reasonable to use the latest stable Boost library as a defacto C++ library. Boost is mostly headers, so you might be surprised with what you consider to be lightweight vs heavyweight.

Comment: Do any of your `process_task` functions dispatch the job to another thread? If so, how do they make sure the object stays alive?

Comment: @David Schwartz The process_task only deal with some business instead of complex behavior such as dispatching the job to other thread. And the shared_ptr make sure the object stays alive

Comment: @Matthias247 User may be need the job after dispatching it. So shared_ptr make the framework more general

Comment: @Brett Hale I have used boost library ever. Thanks for your adviser

Comment: @DanielEdwin Can you show the code that shows precisely how the `shared_ptr` makes sure the object stays alive? It's easy to do it wrong.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Notice declaration of job_dispatch 'void evd_thread_pool::job_dispatch(std::shared_ptr<evd_thread_job> job)'.Its argument 'job' is a copy of source. Of course the reference count will be added at the same time when call this function.User needn't think of freeing memory. Its life is hosted by the shared_ptr

Comment: @DanielEdwin I'm talking about inside the function that does the job. I understand why it's safe when that function is called.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It is just some business code. I can promise there're only some simple behaviors.The job won't be dispatched to other thread.

Comment: @DanielEdwin I'm fairly certain your bug is in that simple business code, likely mishandling the shared pointer in some way.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Please have a look the bottom of the question whether the usage exists any problem

Comment: @DanielEdwin Hmm, perhaps the problem is elsewhere then. Can you give us enough code to replicate the problem?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The source code is at the bottom of the page: https://github.com/raine0524/kbase/blob/master/kbase/evd_thread_impl.cpp. The usage example is at the bottom of the question

Answer (score -1):

I detected a problem in your code, which may or may not be related:

You use `notify_all` from your condition variable. That will awaken ALL threads from sleep. It is OK if you wrap your `wait` in a while loop, like:

```
while (streamline.task_list.empty())
    streamline.cv.wait(lck, [&]()->bool{return !streamline.task_list.empty();});
```

But since you are using an `if`, all threads leave the `wait`. If you dispatch a single product and having several consumer threads, all but one thread will call `wrap = std::move(streamline.task_list.front());` while the tasklist is empty and cause UB.

Comment: Thanks for your adviser, but I think this is not the key point  of crash.Here is the source of my framework: https://github.com/raine0524/kbase/blob/master/kbase/evd_thread_impl.cpp. And the job_dispatch & thread_proc in the bottom of the page

Comment: Actually the task_list & cv is unique in every thread of the pool.And the evd_task_wrap will be created by std::make_shared to push back into the task_list that owns only one thread

Comment: He's using the variant of `wait()` which takes a predicate which defines the wait condition. This is equivalent to the outer while look, so he doesn't need that.

Comment: @Matthias247 right, I've missed that point. Indeed a wrong answer.

Comment: @DanielEdwin is using C++ futures (or maybe shared_future) a no? They should achieve a similar result for this case, in a much simpler way (no need to manage a thread pool and such)

Comment: @BrunoFerreira Can you give me some simple example about this case with shared_future. There's no any example in www.cplusplus.com

Comment: @DanielEdwin there is an example in cppreference.com: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future

Comment: As for a text logger, I made an example here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10e8c3633bdf3240 that uses only std::async (it makes no sense waiting for a void result)